# How to change the names of the url action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, dns

In my url instead of `localhost:45120/Home/Index` we need website names like stackoverflow like that.

How can i implement that for our project using asp.net mvc3.

Comment: You mean you want to remove localhost from the url and put custom name there?

Comment: @BhushanFirake not exactly but generally what the others do. I mean if we open any website then their website name will appear. Similarly i want my own name instead of localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then , you should register a domain name from any domain hosting company. you will have to buy web space from hosting company and redirect your domain name to the ip of the web space you have purchased...

```
**EDIT:**



 routes.MapRoute(
                "Can Be anything", // Route name
                "yourpath/{para1}", // URL with parameters[if you want to have any]
                new { controller = "Quote", action = "Index" }, // Parameter defaults
                new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("GET") }
                );
```

Comment: ok thanks and how can i remove the additional parameters like id and the values

Comment: suppose if we have localhost:787834/Home/index/5 then i want to remove home/index/5 how can i do that

Comment: @Naidu: You are passing 5 as a parameter in the Index method through that url, if you removed that then you will not be able to get the parameter ...!!

Comment: I don't want to remove that i don't need to display that in the url. Not only id but i don't want to display my controller name and action method name

Comment: @Naidu:..Configure your routes in the RouteConfig.cs file in App_Start Folder

Comment: thank you what modifications should be done in RouteConfig.cs

Comment: @Naidu:..Added sample code...just google it if want more details.